# how to fix "Flask 404" for Routing GET POST

Tags: python, html, post, flask, get

I'm starting on Flask.
I have the following **view.py**

My question is regarding the route *@app.route('/uploaded'...*

```
from flask import render_template, jsonify, Flask, redirect, url_for, request
from app import app
import random
import os
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np


@app.route('/')



@app.route('/upload')
def upload_file2():
   return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/uploaded', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      f = request.files['file']
      path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], f.filename)
      model= ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
      img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(224,224))
      x = image.img_to_array(img)
      x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
      x = preprocess_input(x)
      preds = model.predict(x)
      preds_decoded = decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0] 
      print(decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0])
      f.save(path)
      return render_template('uploaded.html', title='Success', predictions=preds_decoded, user_image=f.filename)


@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home')

@app.route('/map')
def map():
    return render_template('map.html', title='Map')


@app.route('/map/refresh', methods=['POST'])
def map_refresh():
    points = [(random.uniform(48.8434100, 48.8634100),
               random.uniform(2.3388000, 2.3588000))
              for _ in range(random.randint(2, 9))]
    return jsonify({'points': points})


@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html', title='Contact')
```

in the .html file, after some verification steps, I ask the End Under upload a file (an image).

Then in my code below, the input is the image and I want as output the results, that must be displayed in  **uploaded**.

However, when I visit **localhost:5000** I can't reach the **uploaded.html**

Is URL is stuck in my PHP request (the one that used to upload the file in my **home.html**)

I read many different answers from this site for similar problems, but none of them solve my issue.

Thanks in advance

> index.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block head %}
    {{ super() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1 class= "ui header" >{{ title }} </h1>
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<h2 class= "ui header" > Hi {{ title }} </h2>


    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

> log:

```
 * Debugger is active!  * Debugger PIN: 127-013-588
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Sep/2019 22:12:18] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Sep/2019 22:12:18] "GET /_debug_toolbar/static/css/toolbar.css?0.2942939835023174 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Sep/2019 22:12:26] "POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: You have a lonely route decorator at the top (`@app.route('/')`), is it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **view.py**, at the index level, try this:

```
@app.route('/index')
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home')
```

You will be able to reach the site either by typing **localhost:5000** or **localhost:5000/index**

Remove the route at the top (`@app.route('/')`) as pointed out by @frankie567.

Comment: Hi @Tobin thanks for reply, but still.. the same error 404.

Comment: can you show the complete error you have in your console? otherwise it is very difficult to determine where this error comes from. But usually a 404 error is used to indicate that the resource was not found. So either you point to the wrong url, or your application just does not run, ...

Comment: Hi again @Tobin find it above, I wrote it. Thanks for your time

Comment: Here are a few quick suggestions: 1. Try to run flask on another port number like **5500**. 2. Clear your browser cache and test ... Tell me if it worked

Answer (score 0):

Using a different port number worked for me! No idea why this worked as I have an alternative flask application that runs on port 8000. Thanks.